# An array of functions

Tags: functions

I need to define an array which every entry is a function. To be more specific, I want to solve the equation:

$$\frac{d \rho}{dt} = -i[H, \rho] + L[\rho]$$

in which $\rho$ is a matrix. This is a coupled differential equation where each element of the matrix $\rho$ depends on the others.

How do I define a matrix of functions in a way that `DSolve` or `DSolveValue` recognize them and solve them?

---

Edit:
I have defined an array for $\rho$

`rho = Table[Subscript[r, i, j], {i, 8}, {j, 8}];`

and also for H, and the operator $L$. Each of the elements of $\rho$ is depend on other elements. For example:

```
    d/dt Subscript[r, 2, 3] = 7 I Subscript[r, 2, 3] - (5 kappa Subscript[r, 2, 3])/(2 (-1 + E^(5/TL))) - (6 kappa Subscript[r, 2, 3])/(-1 + E^(12/TM)) - (
 5 kappa Subscript[r, 2, 3])/(-1 + E^(5/TR)) -  5/2 (1 + 1/(-1 + E^(5/TL))) kappa Subscript[r, 2, 3] - (1 + 1/(-1 + E^(2/TM))) kappa Subscript[r, 2, 3] + 
 5 (1 + 1/(-1 + E^(5/TR))) kappa Subscript[r, 4, 1]
```

These are 32 coupled differential equations (because of Hermiticity condition of $\rho$) and each of the `Subscript[r, i, j]` is a function of time.

I need to define the array for $\rho$ in a way that each entry is a function of time.

BTW, I can solve them by Fourier transform, but for matrices with small sizes

Comment: I don't see how you can solve this unless the matrix is defined.

Comment: Can you express the equation in Mathematica syntax, and indicate the sizes of the matrices (in terms of e.g. `n` if not fixed)?  People may be unfamiliar with your notation.

Comment: size of the matrices are fixed. in my case, it is N=8.

Comment: To make your questions easy for members to answer, a good technique for quality control is to start a new Mathematica notebook and then copy and run your code. If it fails, find the mistake or omission and fix it. When I copy and paste your code beginning with `d/dt Subscript[r,2,3]` it does not run.

Comment: A word of caution. Although `Subscript[r,1,1]` appears to be a variable mathematica does not treat it as a variable. You are strongly encouraged to write the code without the use of subscripts. You can use, `r[1,1]` for example rather than a subscript.

Comment: I think you might be trying to write `D[r[2, 3, t], t] == 
 7 I r[2, 3, 
    t] - (5 kappa r[2, 3, t])/(2 (-1 + E^(5/TL))) - (6 kappa r[2, 3, 
      t])/(-1 + E^(12/TM)) - (5 kappa r[2, 3, t])/(-1 + E^(5/TR)) - 
  5/2 (1 + 1/(-1 + E^(5/TL))) kappa r[2, 3, 
    t] - (1 + 1/(-1 + E^(2/TM))) kappa r[2, 3, t] + 
  5 (1 + 1/(-1 + E^(5/TR))) kappa r[4, 1, t]` where `r` is a function of the matrix index as well `t`.